# Unable to export Pages document as PDF via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, pdf, pages

I try to export Pages document as PDF, and for some reason the app says something is wrong:

```
tell front document of application "Pages"
    export to "Macintosh HD:Users:myName:Documents:xyz.pdf" as PDF
end tell
```

> "Pages got an error: The document “test” could not be exported as “xyz”. Your most recent changes might be lost." number 6

What is the problem there?

(I don't know whether it is worth to mention, but this or apparently very similar code worked for me today. I tested it multiple times. But then it stopped to work. It seems I made some change that I haven't even noticed...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
tell application "Pages"
    export document 1 ¬
        to POSIX file "/Users/myName/Documents/xyz.pdf" as PDF
end tell
```

OR

```
tell application "Pages"
    export document 1 ¬
        to file "Macintosh HD:Users:myName:Documents:xyz.pdf" as PDF
end tell
```